# How to double-sort a tree JSON object using JavaScript sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort `z` object first by `param1`, then `param2`. My attempt returns duplicated object instance, where object parameters are integer and non-unique.

How do I solve this problem?

```
z=[{object1},{object2},{object3},...,{objectN}];
z.sort(function(x,y){
    if(x.param1-y.param1>0){return -1};
    if(x.param1-y.param1<0){return 1};
    if(x.param1-y.param1==0){
        if(x.param2-y.param2>0){return -1};
        if(x.param2-y.param2<0){return 1};
    }; 

});
```

`z` is similar to:

```
z=[{"level":0,"order":0,"t":"section","a":{"class":"ro s-14 m-3"}},
    {"level":1,"order":0,"t":"h1","a":{"class":"tx-1 s-35"},"x":"This is a text"},
    {"level":1,"order":1,"t":"div","a":{"class":"tx-0 m-3"}},
        {"level":2,"order":0,"t":"h2","a":{"class":"tx-0 s-18"},"x":"This is a text"},
        {"level":2,"order":1,"t":"h3","a":{"class":"tx-0 s-14 fw-3"}},
            {"level":3,"order":0,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":1,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":2,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":3,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":4,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":5,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":6,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":7,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":8,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
        {"level":2,"order":2,"t":"h4","x":"This is a text"},
    {"level":1,"order":2,"t":"div","a":{"class":"tx-0 m-3"}},
        {"level":2,"order":0,"t":"h2","x":"This is a text"},
        {"level":2,"order":1,"t":"h3","a":{"class":"tx-0 s-12 fw-3"}},
            {"level":3,"order":0,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":1,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":2,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":3,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":4,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":5,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":6,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":7,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":8,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":9,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":10,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
            {"level":3,"order":11,"t":"li","x":"This is a text"},
        {"level":2,"order":2,"t":"h4","x":"This is a text"},
];
```

Comment: Your first two ifs, and the two ifs inside the last if block are using the same condition, but returning different values. I think you meant to have one doing a less than `<` comparison

Comment: please add some real data for the objects.

Comment: As @PatrickEvans says, you need to change the second `>` in each group to `<`. You also need `return 0` at the very end. BTW, you don't need to test `== 0`; if it's not less than or greater than 0, that's the remaining possibilty.

Comment: Why write `if (x.param1-y.param1>0)` rather than `if (x.param1 > y.param1)`? Do the less-than and greater-than operators not work. Also, if `x.param1` is positive and `y.param1` is negative, then `x.param1-y.param1` will be greater than 0, when in fact `x.param1` is greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a more compact callback for ascending order:

```
z.sort(function (x, y) {
    return x.param1 - y.param1 || x.param2 - y.param2;
});
```

or descending order:

```
z.sort(function (x, y) {
    return y.param1 - x.param1 || y.param2 - x.param2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You implementation problem is for both `param1` and `param2` you doing the same if with different return value which is not correct. The correction of yours would be:

```
z = [ { object1 }, { object2 }, { object3 },...,{ objectN }];
z.sort(function(x,y){
    if(x.param1-y.param1>0){return -1};
    if(x.param1-y.param1<0){return 1};
    if(x.param1-y.param1==0){
        if(x.param2-y.param2>0){return -1};
        if(x.param2-y.param2<0){return 1};
    }; 

});
```

BTW I prefer this more than what you did:

```js
var items = [{ p1: 10, p2: 3 }, { p1: 9, p2: 4 }, { p1: 9, p2: 3 }, { p1: 10, p2: 2 }, { p1: 11, p2: 3 }, ];

items.sort((a, b) => (a.p1 - b.p1) || (a.p2 - b.p2));

console.log(items);
```

As you can see difference of values is meaningful to sort function which allows you to pass result of subtract to be used for ordering. If difference is 0 (which means false too) then it will goes for second param and returns the result of their subtraction.